# How to forward "1" to Python with VBA?

Tags: python, vba

For a project at university, we are trying to send a "1" to a Python script via VBA.
The Python script is not executing the operation with the "1".

VBA code:

```vb
Sub Prozess1()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\Users\sralb\anaconda3\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\sralb\OneDrive - Hochschule Furtwangen\Desktop\1.py 1"

    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

Python script:

```python
import serial
import time
import sys

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

def write(x):
    arduino.write(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))
    time.sleep(0)
for eachArg in sys.argv:
    print(eachArg)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    write('1')
    arduino.close()
```

Comment: you trying to pass data from vba to python?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the purpose (just want to send the 1)

Comment: @LarsB Does it work if you move the "1" out of PythonScript and append it into the `objShell.Run` like so: `objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript & " 1"`?

Comment: No still not working

Comment: `PythonScript` has spaces and so needs to be quoted like `PythonExe` (do not include the "1" in the quoted part though)  `PythonScript = """C:\Users\sralb\OneDrive - Hochschule Furtwangen\Desktop\1.py"" 1"`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `PythonScript` has spaces, and so needs to be quoted like `PythonExe` (do not include the "1" in the quoted part though)

So:

```vb
PythonScript = """C:\Users\sralb\OneDrive - Hochschule Furtwangen\Desktop\1.py"" 1"
```